# R plotly waterfall with offset base: hovertext activated on hover at wrong position

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Recently, when using an offset (a non-zero `base` parameter) in a waterfall plot in plotly, I noticed that the boxes with hoverinfo were activated when the mouse pointer was in a completely wrong/unexpected place. Below I've pasted in screenshots to illustrate the problem.

1. Mouse pointer just to the left of the value in the `base` parameter:
   [image: left of base]
2. Mouse pointer just to the right of the `base`:
   [image: just right of base]
3. Mouse pointer just to the left of the green box:
   [image: just left of green box]
4. Mouse pointer inside the green box (same behavior to the right of the box):
   [image: within green box]

Just found a similar question on the Plotly forum for the Python Dash users [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/waterfall-wrong-position-of-mouse-to-show-hover/52900), but it looks like it hasn't been answered.

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

I'm attaching the code below for reproducing the example shown in the pictures:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)


set.seed(123)
test_x <- rnorm(10)
test_y <- c(LETTERS[1:10], "all") %>% factor(., levels = .)
test_base <- -15

test_data <- tibble(
  x = c(test_x, 0),
  y = test_y,
  text = c(paste("test", 1:10), "all"),
  measure = c(rep("relative", 10), "total")
)


plot_ly(
  test_data,
  type = "waterfall",
  orientation = "h",
  measure = ~measure,
  x = ~x,
  y = ~y,
  base = test_base,
  text = ~text,
  textposition = "none",
  hoverinfo = "text",
  decreasing = list(marker = list(color = "orange"))
) %>%
  layout(
    yaxis = list(autorange = "reversed", title = "y"),
    xaxis = list(title = "x")
  )
```

Comment: I can't believe how long it took me to figure it out. We'll both be slapping our foreheads on this one- it's `base = test_base`. It isn't that you used it incorrectly, but that is what's throwing the plot off. It still should be something that `plotly` package managers investigate. Have you thought about doing that? [Read about their guidelines for that here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: @Kat, without `base = test_base` the offset disappears, and everything behaves as expected. But the question is, how to have the offset and have the hoverinfo boxes pop up in their expected locations? Sorry if your comment already mentions how to do this and I somehow missed it! I think it might be a bug, so I [opened an issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/6161). Thank you for that link, if the issue remains unaddressed, I'll go ahead and see if I can pinpoint it and fix it.

Comment: You could use a literal offset on the x variable by subtracting `x - test_base`. On a separate note, out of curiosity, I created waterfall graphs using the parameter `base` in both Javascript and Python. Neither language took issue with it. I replaced `test_base` with a literal value in all three, as well. Just R suffered. Actually, the functionality of hovering was a lot smoother in the other languages.

Comment: @Kat, looks like I'm still getting it wrong, going with `x - test_base` made it look very different than intended. I've put together [a simplified JS version](https://codepen.io/pharmhax/pen/popLNQa) and ended up with the same problem. I'd be much obliged if you could fix my JS snippet and send me back a coderpen link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a detailed [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/6161) report on the plotly.js GitHub repo, and, unfortunately, it was recognized as a bug. As such, this doesn't seem to have much to do with SO, so I'm posting this answer in case anybody faces the same problem, and said bug hasn't been fixed yet.